# Acessar dados de ficheiro.txt por Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho um ajax + um txt script simples e consigo acessar os dados do txt, mas eu quero que selecionar os dados de um array no ajax, exemplo, buscar só o nome ou só a idade. Veja o código;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadXMLDoc(){
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxnotxt.txt",false);
                xmlhttp.send();
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

e tem um txt chamado `ajaxnotxt.txt` que tem uma variavel assim:

```
var carro = {tipo:"fiat", modelo:"500", cor:"branco"};
```

quero acessar assim:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
carro.tipo;
```

Tentei por assim:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText.carro.tipo;
```

Mas não funcionou. Como acessar determinado dado no `txt` com `ajax`?

Comment: A solução do Sérgio resolve o seu problema, mas já cogitou arrumar um servidor com um SGBD de verdade?

Comment: Oi adailton! Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens 2 maneiras de fazer isso e neste momento estás a tentar uma versão intermédia que é errada.

**Se tens no teu ficheiro `.txt` código JavaScript** como mostras na pergunta:

```
var carro = {tipo:"fiat", modelo:"500", cor:"branco"};
```

então podes carregar esse script não por ajax mas por append de script diretamente na página. Aí a variável `carro` ficará global e podes aceder como queres.

Nesse caso o código deve ser:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'ajaxnotxt.txt';
script.onload  = function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = carro.tipo;
}
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

**Se queres usar AJAX**, então deves mudar no teu ficheiro `.txt` para teres somente uma string JSON que podes depois usar no JavaScript.

Portanto no ficheiro terias `{"tipo":"fiat", "modelo":"500", "cor":"branco"}` e no AJAX:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var carro = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = carro.tipo;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxnotxt.txt", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Esta maneira é melhor e não exporta variáveis para o espaço global...